# JavaScript Error: Object expected

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML page featuring a div with right-to-left scrolling text; the following JavaScript is located between the HEAD tags of the document.

```
function scroll(oid, iid) {
            this.oCont = document.getElementById(oid);
            this.ele = document.getElementById(iid);
            this.width = this.ele.clientWidth;
            this.n = this.oCont.clientWidth;
            this.move = function() {
                this.ele.style.left=this.n + "px"
                this.n--
                if(this.n<(-this.width)){this.n=this.oCont.clientWidth}
            }
        }
        var vScroll
        function setup() {
            vScroll = new scroll("oScroll", "scroll");
            setInterval("vScroll.move()", 20);
            }           
        onload = function(){
            setup()
        }

        $("scroll").hover(function() {
            $("scroll").stop(true, false)
        }, function(){
            scroll();
        });
        scroll();
```

The scrolling text works fine; however I wanted the scrolling to stop on mouse hover. Although the text does stop scrolling when the mouse cursor passes over the div, I get a javascript error "Object expected".
I'm new to javascript and have no idea where I'm going wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: which line does the error point to? It looks like you're trying to reference `this` outside of the proper context

Comment: The page is actually being displayed in a WebBrowser control in a simple WPF application; I think this must be an IE browser; changing the default browser does not affect the functioning of the error message..

Comment: @user1748443: `Object expected` is an IE error.  All other browsers give a much more descriptive and useful error message.  For example: Chrome says `vScroll is not defined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with your `setInterval`.  You are passing it a string!  This makes it use `eval`!  That means the code is ran in global scope, so `vScroll` does not exist.

Instead, pass a function to `setInterval`:

```
setInterval(function(){
    vScroll.move();
}, 20);
```

The function passed to `setInterval` is called  with the "context" (`this` value) set to `null`, so you cannot pass `vScroll.move` directly to `setTimeout`.  You can, however. do:

```
setInterval(vScroll.move.bind(vScroll), 20);
```

but this doesn't work in all browsers.

P.S. Passing a string to `setInterval` is bad practice, you should *always* be passing a function.